# Vim airline plugin bad characters

Tags: vim, fonts, character-encoding, vim-plugins

I'm having issue to display correctly the vim-airline plugin.

Here's what it's supposed to look like
[image: expected]
Here's what it currently looks like.
[image: actual]

Note the `>`, which is not displayed properly.

I tried the first fix on the vim-airline FAQ, no change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What font are you using? You may need to [install the powerline fonts](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/linux.html#fonts-installation).

Alternatively you can hide the separators.

```
" Don't show seperators
let g:airline_left_sep=''
let g:airline_right_sep=''
```

Comment: I'm using mosnospace. I'd like not to install anything (For example if I'm at work), but I'll try to install the powerline fonts at home.

Comment: Working with powerline fonts, had to add let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1 to my .vimrc, thanks!